# stringr Package replace characters

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to replace each character in a string with following rules using stringr package:

```
replace_characters <- function(x){str_replace_all(x,c("A"="N",'B'='O','C'='P','D'='Q','E'='R','F'='S','G'='T','H'='U','I'='V','J'='W','K'='X','L'='Y','M'='Z',
'N'='A','O'='B','P'='C','Q'='D','R'='E','S'='F','T'='G','U'='H','V'='I','W'='J','X'='K','Y'='L','Z'='M','0'='5','1'='6','2'='7','3'='8','4'='9','5'='0','6'='1','7'='2','8'='3','9'='4'))}
```

and then i tried the function with a random string:

```
replace_characters("HSNKSL584")
```

and i got:

```
"HFAKFL034"
```

as you can see some of the letters(numbers) have been replaced as expected but some remain unchanged.
Can anyone explain the reason for me?

Thanks!

Comment: I found that ````stringr::str_replace_all("H",c("H"="U","U"="H"))```` also does nothing to ````"H"````. The replacement is not done simultaneously.

Comment: Isn't it expected? Since you have `A = B` and then `B = A`?

Answer (score 4):

Behind the scenes, `stringr::str_replace_all` calls upon `stringi`'s `stri_replace_all_*` functions. If you used a named vector to describe multiple replacement patterns (which is the case here), the corresponding parameters fed into `stri_replace_all_*` includes `vectorize_all = FALSE`.

From `stri_replace_all_*`'s help file:

> However, for stri_replace_all*, if vectorize_all is FALSE, the each
>   substring matching any of the supplied patterns is replaced by a
>   corresponding replacement string. In such a case, the vectorization is
>   over str, and - independently - over pattern and replacement. In other
>   words, this is equivalent to something like for (i in 1:npatterns) str
>   <- stri_replace_all(str, pattern[i], replacement[i]...

As raymkchow & Sotos have noted in the comments, when you cycle through the replacement patterns one by one sequentially, some are going to get affected more than once, effectively reversing the replacement from an earlier cycle.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `chartr` from `base R`

```
chartr("HSNKL584", "UFAXY039", "HSNKSL584")
#[1] "UFAXFY039"
```

This can be made into a function

```
replace_char_fun <- function(str1) {
  old <- paste(c(LETTERS, 0:9), collapse="")
  new <-  paste(c(LETTERS[14:26], LETTERS[1:13], 5:9, 0:4), collapse="")
  chartr(old, new, str1)
}
replace_char_fun( "HSNKSL584")
#[1] "UFAXFY039"
```